# How to stop a function & exit program running in a while loop on key press?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, python-keyboard

I need to stop a program when a keyboard key q is pressed. How can I achieve that in the below code? How can I ignore `time.sleep` & detect a keypress & exit the program by printing something? Currently, the keypress gets detected only after 10 seconds. Suppose I am pressing q after 3 seconds the program doesn't exit.

```
import sys
import time

import keyboard

def hd():
    print("Hi")
    time.sleep(10)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        print(keyboard.is_pressed("q"))
        sys.exit()


while True:
    hd()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of polling the keyboard to check if a certain key is pressed, you can just add a [hotkey](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.add_hotkey). When the hotkey `q` (or whatever key you like) is pressed, a trigger function `quit` is called.

```
import keyboard
import time
import sys

exitProgram = False

# prepare to exit the program
def quit():
    global exitProgram
    exitProgram=True
    
# set hotkey    
keyboard.add_hotkey('q', lambda: quit())

# main loop to do things
while not exitProgram:
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(1)
    
print("bye bye")
sys.exit()
```

Comment: How is `while not exitProgram: time.sleep(1)` *not* polling the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

`time.sleep()` is a blocking call. Nothing happens in your program while it runs.

Shorten the intervals. For example, instead of sleeping 10 seconds, sleep 100 × 0.1 second.

```
import sys
import time

import keyboard

def hd():
    print("Hi")
    for _ in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            print(keyboard.is_pressed("q"))
            sys.exit()

while True:
    hd()
```

For more complex behavior (doing actual work while also listening for a keyboard event) you will have to look into multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

if you send main thread pid to presskey callback function, you can kill the main thread in child thread, just like this:

```
import os
from time import sleep

import keyboard
import psutil


def on_space():
    print('space was pressed')


def on_x(main_pid):
    print('x was pressed')
    psutilKill(main_pid)


def psutilKill(proc_pid):
    process = psutil.Process(proc_pid)
    for proc in process.children(recursive=True):
        print(f"kill{proc}")
        proc.kill()
    print(f"kill{process}")
    process.kill()


def sleepT(sleepSeconds, msg=""):
    """
    带有倒计时和提示信息的sleep
    """
    while sleepSeconds > 0:
        print(f"\r{msg} sleeping…… %2d 秒" % sleepSeconds, end='')
        sleep(1)
        sleepSeconds = sleepSeconds - 1
    print()


def main():
    main_pid = os.getpid()
    keyboard.add_hotkey('space', on_space)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('x', on_x, args=[main_pid])
    sleepT(100000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```